# Fill in same amount of characters where other column is NaN

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-explode

I have the following dummy dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['a,b,c,d', 'e,f,g,h', 'i,j,k,l,m'],
                   'Col2':['aa~bb~cc~dd', np.NaN, 'ii~jj~kk~ll~mm']})

        Col1            Col2
0    a,b,c,d     aa~bb~cc~dd
1    e,f,g,h             NaN
2  i,j,k,l,m  ii~jj~kk~ll~mm
```

The real dataset has shape `500000, 90`.

I need to unnest these values to rows and I'm using the new `explode` method for this, which works fine.

The problem is the `NaN`, these will cause unequal lengths after the `explode`, so I need to fill in the same amount of delimiters as the filled values. In this case `~~~` since row 1 has three comma's.

---

**expected output**

```
        Col1            Col2
0    a,b,c,d     aa~bb~cc~dd
1    e,f,g,h             ~~~
2  i,j,k,l,m  ii~jj~kk~ll~mm
```

**Attempt 1**:

```
df['Col2'].fillna(df['Col1'].str.count(',')*'~')
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
np.where(df['Col2'].isna(), df['Col1'].str.count(',')*'~', df['Col2'])
```

---

**This works**, but I feel like there's an easier method for this:

```
characters = df['Col1'].str.replace('\w', '').str.replace(',', '~')
df['Col2'] = df['Col2'].fillna(characters)

print(df)

        Col1            Col2
0    a,b,c,d     aa~bb~cc~dd
1    e,f,g,h             ~~~
2  i,j,k,l,m  ii~jj~kk~ll~mm

d1 = df.assign(Col1=df['Col1'].str.split(',')).explode('Col1')[['Col1']]
d2 = df.assign(Col2=df['Col2'].str.split('~')).explode('Col2')[['Col2']]

final = pd.concat([d1,d2], axis=1)
print(final)

  Col1 Col2
0    a   aa
0    b   bb
0    c   cc
0    d   dd
1    e     
1    f     
1    g     
1    h     
2    i   ii
2    j   jj
2    k   kk
2    l   ll
2    m   mm
```

---

**Question**: is there an easier and more generalized method for this? Or is my method fine as is.

Comment: `np.where(df['Col2'].isna(), ['~'*x for x in df['Col1'].str.count(',')], df['Col2'])`?

Comment: Drop the nan, then append it  later on

Comment: Do you need the original Index?

Comment: No I don't @ALollz

Comment: I'm not sure why you are assigning and them exploding on the dataframe, why not operate on the series to simplify the indexing?

Comment: I am following the [`docs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#series-explode-to-split-list-like-values-to-rows) which shows how to unnest a `string` column. @user3483203

Comment: That's if you want to keep the original DataFrame.  In this case, you don't (you just index the original column anyways), and it's only slowing your approach down.  If you removed that, it might be more efficient than some of the answers proposed here.

Comment: You are right, I should only do that for the first `explode` since I have some `id` columns at the front which I need to retain, after that I can do `Series.explode`. Thanks @user3483203

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `pd.concat`

```
delims = {'Col1': ',', 'Col2': '~'}
pd.concat({
    k: df[k].str.split(delims[k], expand=True)
    for k in df}, axis=1
).stack()

    Col1 Col2
0 0    a   aa
  1    b   bb
  2    c   cc
  3    d   dd
1 0    e  NaN
  1    f  NaN
  2    g  NaN
  3    h  NaN
2 0    i   ii
  1    j   jj
  2    k   kk
  3    l   ll
  4    m   mm
```

This loops on columns in `df`.  It may be wiser to loop on keys in the `delims` dictionary.

```
delims = {'Col1': ',', 'Col2': '~'}
pd.concat({
    k: df[k].str.split(delims[k], expand=True)
    for k in delims}, axis=1
).stack()
```

---

#### Same thing, different look

```
delims = {'Col1': ',', 'Col2': '~'}
def f(c): return df[c].str.split(delims[c], expand=True)
pd.concat(map(f, delims), keys=delims, axis=1).stack()
```

Comment: This looks promissing with the `delims` dict. Let me test, but this should be easily maintainable and generalizable to more columns.

Answer (score 4):

One way is using [`str.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.repeat.html) and `fillna()` not sure how efficient this is though:

```
df.Col2.fillna(pd.Series(['~']*len(df)).str.repeat(df.Col1.str.count(',')))
```

---

```
0       aa~bb~cc~dd
1               ~~~
2    ii~jj~kk~ll~mm
Name: Col2, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

`zip_longest` can be useful here, given you don't need the original Index. It will work regardless of which column has more splits:

```
from itertools import zip_longest, chain

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['a,b,c,d', 'e,f,g,h', 'i,j,k,l,m', 'x,y'],
                   'Col2':['aa~bb~cc~dd', np.NaN, 'ii~jj~kk~ll~mm', 'xx~yy~zz']})
#        Col1            Col2
#0    a,b,c,d     aa~bb~cc~dd
#1    e,f,g,h             NaN
#2  i,j,k,l,m  ii~jj~kk~ll~mm
#3        x,y        xx~yy~zz
```

---

```
l = [zip_longest(*x, fillvalue='') 
     for x in zip(df.Col1.str.split(',').fillna(''), 
                  df.Col2.str.split('~').fillna(''))]

pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(l))

    0   1
0   a  aa
1   b  bb
2   c  cc
3   d  dd
4   e    
5   f    
6   g    
7   h    
8   i  ii
9   j  jj
10  k  kk
11  l  ll
12  m  mm
13  x  xx
14  y  yy
15     zz
```

Comment: Just tested it and it produces the wrong output, check row 13,14,15 in your example.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough, but if you check my expected output you can see it. The real dataset is a change history where the first column tracks the column names and the second one notes the change of the value. So the first value should be matched with the first value only in the first row.

Comment: I tried your solution with some edits, I can't get to the correct output unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, I guess it would be tricky if you have ID or other columns that you need to retain.

Answer (score 3):

Just split the dataframe into two

```
df1=df.dropna()
df2=df.drop(df1.index)

d1 = df1['Col1'].str.split(',').explode()
d2 = df1['Col2'].str.split('~').explode()
d3 = df2['Col1'].str.split(',').explode()

final = pd.concat([d1, d2], axis=1).append(d3.to_frame(),sort=False)
Out[77]: 
  Col1 Col2
0    a   aa
0    b   bb
0    c   cc
0    d   dd
2    i   ii
2    j   jj
2    k   kk
2    l   ll
2    m   mm
1    e  NaN
1    f  NaN
1    g  NaN
1    h  NaN
```

Comment: This comes closest to what I want, the problem is that I have quite some of these columns