# How to populate multiple dictionary with common keys to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of dictionaries where keys are identical but values in each dictionary is not same, and the order of each dictionary strictly preserved. I am trying to find an automatic solution to populate these dictionaries to pandas dataframe as new column, but didn't get the expected output.

**original data on gist**

here is the data that I have on [old data on gist](https://gist.github.com/forzaPhd/c12ff1f5572a61df49c2eb476726a74d).

**my attempt**

here is my attempt to populate multiple dictionaries with same keys but different values (binary value), my goal is I want to write down handy function to vectorize the code. Here is [my inefficient code but works on gist](https://gist.github.com/forzaPhd/adc7bf97cbacdafddc707832186d437a)

```
import pandas as pd

dat= pd.read_csv('old_data.csv', encoding='utf-8')

dat['type']=dat['code'].astype(str).map(typ)
dat['anim']=dat['code'].astype(str).map(anim)
dat['bovin'] = dat['code'].astype(str).map(bov)
dat['catg'] = dat['code'].astype(str).map(cat)
dat['foot'] = dat['code'].astype(str).map(foo)
```

my code works but it is not vectorized (not efficient I think). I am wondering how can I make this few lines of a simple function. Any idea? how to we make this happen as efficiently as possible?

Here is my current and the desired output:

since I got correct output but code is not well efficient here. this is my current output on [gist](https://gist.github.com/forzaPhd/76f2b42825f7e6f1c31e27b26fe92a4b)

Comment: You cannot post your full data and full code and expect people to go through it for you and debug it. When asking your question, you have supply a small example which represents your actual problem. This way you also force yourself to understand your problem fully. Have a look at one of my [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57774352/fill-in-same-amount-of-characters-where-other-column-is-nan)

Comment: @Erfan there is no bug in my code, just want to simplify the process of populating multople dictionaries to pandas. if I posted my current code to `SO` it is gonna be a long post that might be a burden to `SO` community. How can I simplify my current attempt? any idea?

Comment: @Erfan is correct, there is no way to reproduce your code if you use a read_excel. Reduce the example to something that can be copy/pasted to an editor and works immediately from there, then people can reproduce it and start working from there.

Comment: All the links are broken, please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you restructure your dictionaries into a dictionary of dictionaries you can one line it:

```
 for keys in values.keys():
        dat[keys]=dat['code'].astype(str).map(values[keys])
```

Full code:

```
values = {"typ" :{
    '20230' : 'A',
    '20130' : 'A',
    '20220' : 'A',
    '20120' : 'A',
    '20329' : 'A',
    '20322' : 'A',
    '20321' : 'B',
    '20110' : 'B',
    '20210' : 'B',
    '20311' : 'B'
    } ,

"anim" :{
    '20230' : 'AOB',
    '20130' : 'AOB',
    '20220' : 'AOB',
    '20120' : 'AOB',
    '20329' : 'AOC',
    '20322' : 'AOC',
    '20321' : 'AOC',
    '20110' : 'AOB',
    '20210' : 'AOB',
    '20311' : 'AOC'
    } ,

"bov" :{
    '20230' : 'AOD',
    '20130' : 'AOD',
    '20220' : 'AOD',
    '20120' : 'AOD',
    '20329' : 'AOE',
    '20322' : 'AOE',
    '20321' : 'AOE',
    '20110' : 'AOD',
    '20210' : 'AOD',
    '20311' : 'AOE'
    } ,

"cat" :{
    '20230' : 'AOF',
    '20130' : 'AOG',
    '20220' : 'AOF',
    '20120' : 'AOG',
    '20329' : 'AOF',
    '20322' : 'AOF',
    '20321' : 'AOF',
    '20110' : 'AOG',
    '20210' : 'AOF',
    '20311' : 'AOG'
    } ,

"foo" :{
    '20230' : 'AOL',
    '20130' : 'AOL',
    '20220' : 'AOM',
    '20120' : 'AOM',
    '20329' : 'AOL',
    '20322' : 'AOM',
    '20321' : 'AOM',
    '20110' : 'AOM',
    '20210' : 'AOM',
    '20311' : 'AOM'
    } 
}




import pandas as pd

dat= pd.read_csv('old_data.csv', encoding='utf-8')
for keys in values.keys():
    dat[keys]=dat['code'].astype(str).map(values[keys])
```

Comment: Can’t you specify the data type using a dict, or even just `dtype=str`, in `pandas.read_csv()`?